# setting up a postgres server connection is not working in linqpad 5

Tags: c#, postgresql, connection, connection-string, linqpad5

I am new to using `linqpad 5`. I am working with Postgres databases. I wanted to set up a connection in linqpad but there is no driver to connect for Postgres, so I added linqpad-PostgreSQL-driver: https://github.com/fknx/linqpad-postgresql-driver

while setting up a connection like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZfDn.png), I am getting an error saying **unable to connect to server: Authentication method not supported(Recieved:10)** like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY9UY.png)

what have I done wrong here? I even tried using connection string like this:

```
"Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
```

but not working.

Comment: First this link change radio button option to connection string,

Comment: I changed that and placed connection string also, but not working

Comment: Same error message?

Comment: yes, same error message again

Comment: The connection string can vary depending on driver. It could be UID instead of User Id.  See : https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/?force_isolation=true  Try also setting the SSL parameter.